# Autocomplete in JQuery is not working properly

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use jquery auto complete .it is not working properly it showing only one option every time i don't why i am getting this.

**Code**

```
var options_df1 = {
        serviceUrl: '/'+company+'/city_names.html',
        width: 230,
        minChars: 1,
        maxHeight: 500,
        delimiter: /(,|;)\s*/,
        onSelect: onAutocompleteSelect_df1,
        deferRequestBy: 0, //miliseconds
        params:{country: 'Yes'},
        };

var onAutocompleteSelect_df1 = function(value_df, data_df) {
            startlocation_df = data_df;
        }
```

Comment: please explain u r problem more

Comment: every time it is shwoing only the first value that is searched

Comment: You mean the autocomplete box only shows one item when you search, when it should be showing multiple items?

Comment: You're trying to do this on an input ?

Comment: only the first value that is searched it showing that

Comment: Typeahead.js may help you http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/ Am I right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope the problem is because of caching Use this code .Use noCache property

```
var options_df1 = {
        serviceUrl: '/'+company+'/city_names.html',
        width: 230,
        minChars: 1,
        maxHeight: 500,
        delimiter: /(,|;)\s*/,
        onSelect: onAutocompleteSelect_df1,
        deferRequestBy: 0, //miliseconds
        params:{country: 'Yes'},
        noCache: false //set to true, to disable caching

        };
```

Comment: i got my problem i was missing this